# Quadratic Formula returning an error

Tags: c#

I'm working on a program, and I'm using the quadratic formula. This is the code that executes when a button is clicked, to solve the problem,

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double aVal, bVal, cVal, xVal1, xVal2;
    xVal1 = 0;
    xVal2 = 0;
    aVal = Convert.ToDouble(a.Text);
    bVal = Convert.ToDouble(b.Text);
    cVal = Convert.ToDouble(c.Text);
    xVal1 = (bVal + Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(bVal, 2) - (4 * aVal * cVal))) / 2 * aVal; //Positive Calculation
    xVal2 = (bVal - Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(bVal, 2) - (4 * aVal * cVal))) / 2 * aVal; //Negative Calculation
    xPos.Text = Convert.ToString(xVal1);
    xNeg.Text = Convert.ToString(xVal2);
}
```

After some debugging, I believe I've narrowed the issue down to line 9 and 10, where the actual math takes place. However, I'm not quite sure what's wrong. As you can see, the numbers are doubles, and are initialized, so they are not null, or truncating. When I run the program and input a b and c values of say, 6, 4, and 3, the xPos and xNeg labels which are responsible for outputting the negative and positive values, simply display NaN. Should I be using a label for this sort of thing?

Comment: Have you checked to make sure that the Convert.ToDouble worked as expected?  Have you tried using Double.Parse or Double.TryParse instead?

Comment: What is the exact formula you're trying to emulate?

Comment: It looks like somebody should try understanding the quadratic formula. The example you give, say 6x^2 + 4x + 3 has no real roots. What else but NaN do you expect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The result of `Math.Pow(bVal, 2) - (4 * aVal * cVal)` is `-56` for the input values of 6, 4, and 3. When you obtain the `Sqrt` of a negative you get the result `NaN`.

You also need to use the correct formula. You should have:

```
var sqrt = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(bVal, 2.0) - (4.0 * aVal * cVal));
var xVal1 = (-bVal + sqrt) / (2.0 * aVal); //Positive Calculation
var xVal2 = (-bVal - sqrt) / (2.0 * aVal); //Negative Calculation
```

Note the `-` in front of the first `bVal` and the brackets around the `2 * aVal`.

I've also expressed the constants with a `.0` as this tells the compiler that you are using doubles. It is quite easy to get incorrect results if you do not do this.

Comment: oh geese, I can't believe I missed that. Lol, thanks for pointing that out, I guess I got so wrapped in the problem that I wasn't paying attention.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static double[] SolveQuadratic(double a, double b, double c)
    {
        return new[]
        {
            (-b + Math.Sqrt(b*b - 4*a*c))/2*a,
            (-b - Math.Sqrt(b*b - 4*a*c))/2*a
        };
    }
```

Then do just:

```
        double x1Val = SolveQuadratic(a, b, c)[0];
        double x2Val = SolveQuadratic(a, b, c)[1];

        textX1.Text = x1Val.ToString();
        textX2.Text = x2Val.ToString();
```